# Looking for better logical XOR solution with strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing some code to evaluate the presence of a bunch of strings, and I want to ensure that only 1 is present.  They're mutually exclusive.

```
class MyClass
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
  validate :mutex_values 

  def initialize(attr = {}) 
    attr.each do |k, v| 
      send("#{k}=", v)
    end 
  end 

  private 
  def mutex_values 
    # here, I want to do this:
    # errors.add(:base, "specify only 1") unless a ^ b ^ c
    # instead I do this
    errors.add(:base, "specify only 1") unless a.present? ^ b.present? ^ c.present?
  end
end 
MyClass.new(:a => "A", :b => "B", :c => "C").valid? 
=> false
```

Is there another way that doesn't require repetitive use of the `.present?`?  Monkey patch String to define an operator `^`?  I'm just so used to being able to do `if a` that it feels unnatural to need what is basically an explicit cast to boolean.  I feel like this use case would 'just work' in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerable actually defines a `one?` method which does exactly what you need.

```
# So either...

[a, b, c].one?(&:present?)

# or

[a, b, c].one?(&:presence)

# ... would do the trick in this case.
```

Unfortunately if you want `two?` or etcera, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this with [`count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001483):

```
errors.add(:base 'specify exactly 1') unless [a, b, c].count(&:present?) == 1
```

If you want at most one instead of exactly one, then:

```
errors.add(:base 'specify at most 1') unless [a, b, c].count(&:present?) > 1
```

For example:

```
> ['',nil,'6',''].count(&:present?)
=> 1 
> ['',nil,'6',11].count(&:present?)
=> 2 
> ['',nil,''].count(&:present?)
=> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether exactly one of methods `a`, `b`, and `c` returns non-null value, you can use:

```
[a, b, c].compact.count == 1
```

or even, thanks to numbers,

```
[a, b, c].one?
```

Comment: It isn't explicitly stated in the question, but I believe the issue is that he's looking for empty strings to behave as though they're null (falsey).

Comment: I really am looking for a logical XOR operator for use with strings.  I'm fine counting `""` as true, since it means the client set it (or tried to).  I was using `present?` in the question because the only other way I know to turn `"a"` into `true` was with `!!`, but that causes a warning.

Comment: Strings are truthy in Ruby, no need to convert them to booleans. The only falsey values are null (which probably you have when the user doesn't set an attribute) and false.

Comment: They're truthy, but not true.  You can't do `^` operations directly on strings, nor can I find a logical version of XOR in ruby (vs a bitwise version which is what `^` is).  That's the root of my question.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the context of XORing things here. You said you want to ensure only one is set. On the other hand, for example, `true ^ true ^ true` gives `true`.