# Form validation on combination of input fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form which has several fields. On the Rails side there are some validations which work fine. But I also a requirement where the combination of two input fields should be validated.

The attributes are `project_id` and `unbillable_id`. Only one of them should be filled with with a value, so it should fail when both fields are filled or when both fields are empty. How should I do this?

This is the controller:

```
  def create
    authorize! :create, Activity

    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @activity.save
        format.js { render :action => "create_success"}
      else
        format.js { render :action => "create_failure"}
      end
    end
  end
```

And this is create_failure.js.erb:

```
alert("Failed to upload record: <%= j @activity.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for [XOR validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134188/validate-presence-of-one-field-or-another-xor)

In your case, `app/models/activity.rb` should behave it as follows:

**Option-1:**

class Activty < ActiveRecord::Base

```
validates :project_id, presence: true, allow_nil: true
validates :unbillable_id, presence: true, allow_nil: true


validate :xor_activity

private

def xor_activity
  unless (project_id.blank? ^ unbillable_id.blank?)
    errors.add(:base, "Specify a Project or a Unbillable, not both")
  end
end
```

end

**Option-2:**
Form an array and count the number of elements - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7369899/1125893

Comment: Thanks, I like your option 1

Answer (score 0):

Use [callback](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) in the model to check if they're both `present?`

Answer (score 0):

This should exist as a custom validation, in the model.

```
#in app/models/activity.rb
validate :must_have_project_id_or_unbillable_id

def must_have_project_id_or_unbillable_id
  if (self.project_id.blank? and self.unbillable_id.blank?) ||
     (!self.project_id.blank? and !self.unbillable_id.blank?)
    self.errors.add(:project_id, "must have either project_id or unbillable id (but not both)")
    self.errors.add(:unbillable_id, "must have either project_id or unbillable id (but not both)")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @activity.project_id.nil? && @activity.unbillable_id.nil?
    format.js { render :action => "create_failure"}
  elsif @activity.project_id.present? && @activity.unbillable_id.present?
    format.js { render :action => "create_failure"}
  elsif @activity.save
    format.js { render :action => "create_success"}
  else
    format.js { render :action => "create_failure"}
  end
end
```